# The efficiency of "in" and "for" operations in python

Tags: python, performance

I got two lists here, called A and B.

```
len(A) > len(B)
```

There are two ways to do something:

Method one:

```
def f():
    return [someFunc(i) for i in A if i in B]
```

Method two:

```
def f():
    return [someFunc(i) for i in B if i in A]
```

Which one is more efficient and why?

Comment: Your functions won't do the same thing. If `A=[2,2,2,2,2]` and `B=[2]`, then your first function would return a list containing 5 elements and `someFunc` gets called 5 times, while your second function would return a list with a single element.

Comment: @Kimvais `>` means greater than; `>>` means much greater than.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus Yeah, now I see they won't do the same thing. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Both are O(mn), since you're iterating over each list for each element of the other list.

Answer (score 4):

While the time complexity for the `in` operation is `O(n)` and so the whole operation is `O(nm)`, this applies mainly to how it scales with problem size. Performance-wise, apart from a worst-case scenario where `A` and `B` are mutually exclusive, it should be faster to do `for B if i in A` (where `len(A) > len(B)`) since `in` would stop iterating once a match is found.

Consider the best-case scenario where all entries in `A` and `B` have the same value. The `in` operation would effectively be `O(1)` and the whole operation `O(m)`.

And everyone's favourite, some benchmarks:

```
$ python -m timeit "A=list(range(100000));B=list(range(100))" "[i for i in A if i in B]"
10 loops, best of 3: 113 msec per loop

$ python -m timeit "A=list(range(100000));B=list(range(100))" "[i for i in B if i in A]"
100 loops, best of 3: 2.6 msec per loop
```

Performance aside, do note that the two functions you provided *do not do the same thing*. The first iterates through `A` and discards values that do not appear in `B` and this is not the same as iterating through `B` and discarding values that do not appear in `A`. Going back to the scenario where all values in both list are the same, the first function will return `len(A)` elements while the second `len(B)` elements.

Answer (score 3):

```
def f(A, B):
    return [someFunc(_) for _ in set(A).intersection(B)]
```

should be the most efficient way of doing this (at least if the lists are long enough for the time complexity to be of issue)

Comment: I have benchmarks showing others. There's an overhead in converting the list to a set, so this may not be worth it unless the operation is to be performed multiple times.

Comment: Try `python -m timeit "A=list(range(100000));B=list(range(100))" "[i for i in B if i in A]"` vs `python -m timeit "A=list(range(100000));B=list(range(100))" "[i for i in set(A).intersection(B)]"`

Comment: @ShawnChin `B=list(range(50000,50100))` would make a more balanced benchmark, and the set wins by factor of 10.

Comment: Or if the lists are long - with 10k & 10M lists the set approach is faster (and probably will get relatively faster with larger inputs)

Comment: Sets have a limitation over lists: their contents need to be hashable. So sets may not include mutable containers, while lists do.